# what's those line meaning in magento?

Tags: magento

```
<?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
    <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
        <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
        <h2><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></span></h2>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
```

what's those line meaning in magento?

Answer (score 2):

1. foreach over each child (that is grouped by name detailed_info with method getchildhtml) and output the data from those blocks
2. get the html of product_additional_data block

Comment: where are $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') and product_additional_data block? i want to see what content in it? how do i do?

Comment: `product_additional_data` is defined in catalog.xml e.g. `<block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />` now This will render the html page /catalog/product/view/additional.phtml

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet of code from the catalog/product/view.phtml that displays Description, Custom Options, and other detailed product information in the front end view.