# What are the dependancies of the child html under .box-collatoral - Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am trying to understand the dependancies of catalog/product.view.phtml. A lot seems to depend on the following code:

```
 <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias =>$html):?>
<div class="box-collateral < ?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>
<?php echo $html;?>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

With this code in place I can pull in the product options, availabilty and buy now button  with the following code:

```
 <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
 <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
    <?php endif;?>
 <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

The difficulity is I wish to have them appear after the description which is contained within .box-collateral

This seems to present a problem in so much as when I move the latter snippet above the first one, the buy now button still appears but the options do not- (the same thing happens when I simply remove the first snippet)- leading in me to think that these depend on some of the data being pulled by this?

I am able to add the description at the bottom using

```
 <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

however hacky css aside I still can't find a way to stop the description appearing above.

Any pointers, directions or consise explainations appreciated.

(I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026711/whats-those-line-meaning-in-magento) but the file the answer points to just leads to more child_html I don't know the origin of)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to play with the corresponding layout ? (catalog.xml : nodes container1 container2 and wrappers

Comment: looking in catalog.xml it appears that inside the 'structural block' <content there is a 'content block' named product.info. Inside <product.info there are blocks relating to the phtml files above. these blocks all apear to be on top of each other rather than nested. Attempting to move container1/2 nodes above the product.description node leads to the page not outputting options/buy now html. I know this is an issue with my understanding of the block system, however I am not sure where as I have had some success in moving a simpler block.